# Can someone check the header? I added multiple script files which causes many problems

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, scrollview, datebox

I added the header, this causes all html form submits to occur twice and checkboxes dont work. The problem happened by adding jquery mobile datebox and scrollview.
Any help would be great.

```
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqm-docs.css")"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
            // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
            // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page, or when clicking "back"
            // after a form post), hence disabling it.
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
            $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile.scrollview.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jqm-docs.css")"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i8n.en.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile.docs.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.easing.1.3.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/scrollview.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/hub/hub.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile.css")" />  
</head>
```

Comment: You should really consider to bundle and minimize all those JS- and CSS-files.

Comment: I suggest you to remove all of the unnecessary things and including one by one until you find the culprit. Just by Looking at a bunch of includes its hard to figure out.

Comment: You should add your js code after all the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'm gonna try it out and report back.

Answer (score 0):

That script was causing all the problems. Next time I'll bundle everything and add one at a time to avoid all this.